# Query to return sum of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query to return total , tax and a grandTotal of sum and tax for a bill . But the problem is since i am using sum() it only returns the first how can i retrieve all the rows and grand total ?

```
SELECT sum(
            at_salesbill.`billedTotal` + at_salesbill.`billedTotalTax`
            ) as grantTotal,
       at_salesbill.`billedTotal` AS at_salesbill_billedTotal,
       at_salesbill.`billedTotalTax` AS billedTotalTax,
  FROM at_salesbill
 WHERE at_salesbill.`billGuid` = 44;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the values to get the sum:

```
SELECT (at_salesbill.`billedTotal`+at_salesbill.`billedTotalTax`) as grantTotal,
       at_salesbill.`billedTotal` AS at_salesbill_billedTotal,
       at_salesbill.`billedTotalTax` AS billedTotalTax,
from at_salesbill
where at_salesbill.`billGuid` = 44;
```

Then, you can do a trick to get the total along with the value, assuming you have a unique `id` in the row:

```
SELECT at_salesbill.id,
       sum(at_salesbill.`billedTotal`+at_salesbill.`billedTotalTax`) as grantTotal,
       at_salesbill.`billedTotal` AS at_salesbill_billedTotal,
       at_salesbill.`billedTotalTax` AS billedTotalTax,
from at_salesbill
where at_salesbill.`billGuid` = 44
group by at_salesbill.id with rollup;
```

Here, the `sum()` does nothing interesting -- because there is one row in each group.  However, the `with rollup` will add a total column, where the `id` is `NULL`.

```
SELECT (case when at_salesbill.id is NULL then 'total' else '' end),
       sum(at_salesbill.`billedTotal`+at_salesbill.`billedTotalTax`) as grantTotal,
       at_salesbill.`billedTotal` AS at_salesbill_billedTotal,
       at_salesbill.`billedTotalTax` AS billedTotalTax,
from at_salesbill
where at_salesbill.`billGuid` = 44
group by at_salesbill.id with rollup;
```